# Django set default value with include

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have my base html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>default value</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    </head>

<body >

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

And I have  my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
```

I want to be able to rewrite contents of 
`<head>` tag . And use default head tag if no head content is present. How do I do this? For example on some pages I want to use additional meta tags and different title. But I need default title and meta tags if no `<head>` tag  is specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some parts of the `base template` inside `{% block %}{% endblock %}`, you actually have some default contents.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}default value{% endblock title %}</title>
    {% block meta %} <!-- default meta -->
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

When you extend your `base.html`, you just need to call these blocks..

In case you want to overwrite one of these tags, just call the tag:

```
{% block title %}I destroy the default title {% endblock %}
{% block meta %}I destroy the default tag {% endblock %}
```

Comment: what if  I want to have a default meta tag, but want to be able to rewrite it?

Comment: You can add a new block.. {% block default_tag %}{% endblock %} for instance.... when you extend the html, you call it to overwrite its content

Comment: can you update the answer to show me an example how to add a default meta tag and replace it if neccecary?